# Applying text formatting to group name labels in gt package

Tags: r, gt

How can we target individual groupname_col labels for text formatting in `gt()` package when multiple groups are specified? In the example below, I'd like to make the "group" variable bold, but not "char".

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

head(exibble) %>%
gt(rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = c("group", "char")) %>%
tab_style(
  style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
  locations = cells_row_groups(groups = c(1))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `gt::text_transform` which allows for formatting via a custom function. To this end we can split the `row_group` string into pieces and format each piece individually using markdown or HTML:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

row_group_sep <- " - " # Default row_group.sep

head(exibble) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = c("group", "char")) %>%
  gt::text_transform(
    locations = cells_row_groups(),
    fn = function(x) {
      lapply(x, function(x) {
        x <- strsplit(x, split = row_group_sep)[[1]]
        gt::md(paste0("**", x[[1]], "**", row_group_sep, x[[2]]))
      })
    }
  )
```

[image]